# Solidity Error : Types in storage containing (nested) mappings cannot be assigned

Tags: solidity

Solidity Error : Types in storage containing (nested) mappings cannot be assigned

```
  struct Inbox {
    uint numSentMessages;
    uint numReceivedMessages;
    mapping (uint => Message) sentMessages;
    mapping (uint => Message) receivedMessages;
  }

  mapping (address => Inbox) userInboxes;
  mapping (address => bool) hasRegistered;

  Inbox[] newInbox;
  uint donationsInWei = 0;
  Message newMessage;
  ContractProperties contractProperties;

  
//Error 
function clearInbox() public {
     userInboxes[msg.sender]=newInbox;
           
  }

  function registerUser() public {
    if(!hasRegistered[msg.sender]) {
      userInboxes[msg.sender]=newInbox;
      hasRegistered[msg.sender] = true;
      contractProperties.registeredUsersAddress.push(msg.sender);
      
    }
  }
```

(error: showing in the both line of userInboxes[msg.sender]=newInbox;
pls do help me out to solve this. )

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also the code in the screenshot doesn't provide a reproducible example (can't copypaste the code into IDE and produce the same error, can't see what data type is `userInboxes`,). Please edit your question so that it shows a minimal, reproducible code, the actual behavior and the desired behavior. You can find more tips in the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: Thanks you bro @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1693192/petr-hejda , please to help me to solve this problem